# Site not responding while flushing cache

Tags: 7, caching

I have a Drupal 7 site which requires flushing the cache from time to time. The problem is that whenever I flush the cache (~30 seconds) the site is non-responsive until the flush is over.

What could be the cause and how do I debug this?
Thanks

Comment: There can be multiple problems for this, huge database size, large number of modules, huge number of content, etc. You'll have to check through various scenarios.

Comment: The database is ~150mb, the site is modest. As I understand clearing the cache should never cause the site to become unresponsive, maybe just slow it down a bit.

Comment: Maybe a list of used modules?

Comment: many of them. Some custom made.. Main one is ubercart for eCommerce. How would you debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a MySQL frontend like phpMyAdmin run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` while your site is locked from the cache clear. That should show what is causing the issues for you. My guess is it will be a metadata lock. https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc was built to prevent db locks in database caused by the cache.